# JQuery ajax request to php won't execute?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to load items from MySQL to a select element. so  i wrote an ajax code and a php code. the problem is anywhere of the php code doesn't execute. no errors also. (the url is correct).
please help me.
Here is the jQuery code

```
$('#loadButton').click(function () {
console.log("clicked"); //this prints
$.ajax({
    url: "api/service/RoomTypeService.php",
    method: "POST",
    async: true,
    data: "&operation=getAll",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function (resp) {
    alert(resp);
    console.log(resp);
    for (let i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
        alert(resp); //this won't run
        let roomType = resp[i];
        $('#roomTypeCombo').append('<option>' + roomType[1] + '</option>');
    }
});
});
```

and this is complete php code

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__."/../dto/RoomTypeDTO.php";
require_once __DIR__."/../business/impl/RoomTypeBOimpl.php";


echo "Here in service"; //doesn't execute 

$roomTypeBo=new RoomTypeBOimpl();

$method=$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

switch ($method){
 case "POST":
    $operation=$_POST["operation"];
    switch ($operation){
        case "getAll":
            echo json_encode($roomTypeBo->getAllRoomTypes());
            break;
    }
    break;
  case "GET":

 }
```

Comment: change this `data: "&operation=getAll",` to `data: {operation: "getAll"},` (which won't solve not reaching "Here in service", though. I know)

Comment: When you call the php script directly in browser, do you then see "Here in service"? And what do you see now in network tab as return after executing the ajax?

Comment: Why do you think the php part isn't executed? Did you check the network tab of the developer tools?

Comment: @Jeff. Thanks. The result prints in network tab. But it doesn't come to done method. So i added a fail method in ajax and now it runs instead of done.

Comment: The `fail` handler (one of its arguments) will tell you what the problem is

Comment: likely you get an error for not beeing able to parse the returned json (because you echo something before the actual json string)

Comment: @Andreas. It gives only an object. Nothing says.

Comment: @Jeff. Stil the same.

Comment: _"(**one** of its argument**s**)"_ - There are **three** of them -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: The error gives no cause yet bro :(

Comment: I used responseText to print error. It prints the result of json data which i need. Which i don't know why. So I tried to add the loop to append them to combo but nothing happened as i think unlike done respinse, it's not a json array in fail response .

Comment: Now the result comes, i figured it out as there is an echo in php file and it fails to fetch to jason. But still the data doesn't append to combo. But they print correctly in console.log.